# Access: converting form result to table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-forms

I created a basic search form which has input fields, buttons and area where it displays result.

keyword is entered to input fields, and click "search" button to display results.

the search button has the following code:

```
Private Sub mySearchQuery_Click()
Dim strSelect As String
Dim strWhere As String

If Len(Trim(Me!searchFirst.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND First_Name Like ""*" & Me!searchFirst.Value & "*"""
End If 
If Len(Trim(Me!searchLast.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND Last_Name Like ""*" & Me!searchLast.Value & "*"""
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchState.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND State Like ""*" & Me!searchState.Value & "*"""
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchLIC.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND LIC Like ""*" & Me!searchLIC.Value & "*"""
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchNPN.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND NPN Like ""*" & Me!searchNPN.Value & "*"""
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchEmail.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND Email Like ""*" & Me!searchEmail.Value & "*"""
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchDateFrom.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND EXP >= #" & Me.searchDateFrom.Value & "#"
End If
If Len(Trim(Me!searchDateTo.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND EXP <= #" & Me.searchDateTo.Value & "#"
End If  

strSelect = "SELECT * FROM MasterData"
If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
strSelect = strSelect & " WHERE " & Mid(strWhere, 6)
End If

Me.RecordSource = strSelect
' SubForm.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

This search button would search item based on given criteria.  If I input "NY" in State input field and press Search button, it would show result that state is set to NY.

My question is: how do i export this returned result from form to table and save it? it would be nice if i can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use simple SQL. Not that hard.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM MasterData" & strWhere
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  can i make a button for this?  or could you tell me where I can put this code?

Comment: You can make a button, but then you will need to save strWhere in a place where it will persist outside of your search function (declaration section of the module or tempvars). Or you can add it as an option in your search function.